# Docker build: returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This line causes my docker build to fail. I've tried splitting it up but get different errors. What would be the proper way to define this line?

```
    ARG lame=3.99.5
    RUN curl -L         http://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/lame/3.99/lame-${lame}.tar.gz |         tar -xzf- && \
      cd lame-${lame} && \
      ./configure && make install
```

I get this error:

```
    Step 13/38 : RUN curl -L http://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/lame/3.99/lame-${lame}.tar.gz | tar -xzf- &&   cd lame-${lame} &&   ./configure && make install
     ---> Running in 1d9635c2e249
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100   178  100   178    0     0    456      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   456
      0   345    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
      0 15608    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
      0   341    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
    100 1411k  100 1411k    0     0   166k      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--  334k
    checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether build environment is sane... yes
    checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
    checking for style of include used by make... GNU
    checking for gcc... no
    checking for cc... no
    checking for cl.exe... no
    configure: error: in `/usr/local/src/lame-3.99.5':
    configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
    See `config.log' for more details
    The command '/bin/sh -c curl -L http://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/lame/3.99/lame-${lame}.tar.gz | tar -xzf- &&   cd lame-${lame} &&   ./configure && make install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Here's a hint: `No acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`.

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh that was it thanks!